# octal-form literal doesn't convert to decimal

Tags: c#, literals

I followed how to write octal literal but it seems not working:

```
int b = 0145;
Console.WriteLine(b); // prints 145
```

I'm trying to convert from octal to decimal, I tried hex and binary literals and it's working fine but not octal. What's the problem?

Comment: Use Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 8)), where the 2nd parameter to Convert.ToString is the numeric base (2,8,10,16, etc).

Comment: What is an "octal literal"? `0145` is an Int32 literal, which you are assigning to an Int32, and printing it using the Int32 parameter.

Comment: Ouch. Yeah, always look for the spec. Good SO answers are generally also pretty safe to rely on especially if they cite specs. You sure you weren't on a C/C++ site?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Nope, I were on geeksforgeeks they had the same answer and  they didn't write that it's not working, I dont know why tho

Comment: Oh, [was this the page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-literals/)? Yeah, they're wrong for sure. In general, for language references, you'll want to try to stick with more reputable sources. For C#, use MS's own docs. For web (JS/HTML/CSS), use MDN, or if not there, the official W3 spec (*not* W3Schools). Good, reliable SO posts tend to point to those sites as well.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance yes that page